# virtual env python 3.5 only finds django python 2.7

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-venv

I have created python 3.5.2 virtual environment ("python --version" confirms that)

but when i try to install django using "pip install django~=1.10.0" I get this message:

> Requirement already satisfied: django~=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

How can I get django version that agrees with the python version in my venv?

Comment: did you activate the virtual environment?

Comment: yes I did. But I already found the reason. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probabily you have already installed django outside the venv with python2.
just write see in the pip list if django is installed.
Then uninstall, enter in the venv and reinstall django with python3

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use [conda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) to manage environments and I'm not really familiar with virtualenv, but a few things to check.

I bet you need to use pip3 not pip (aka pip2) to install django that way it will be installed in your python 3 env.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so I figured out what happened. I have installed django using sudo pip install. Even though I was in the venv (created with python3) this has resulted in reference to django outside the venv. Sooo...it was an interesting thing to learn I guess.